# Is it possible to settle the Boston Airport?

Tags: fallout-4

I've settled every settlement in the main Fallout 4 game. Except the Boston Airport. I can't seem to figure this one out. I can't craft a beacon radio here and it doesn't even give me an option to plant crops (food doesn't even show as a resource in the workshop interface). Just for reference, this is post

> Prydwyn explosion

in case that makes a difference. I'd really like to 100% the settlement aspect of this game and the 0% staring at me from the Boston Airport is really grating on my nerves. Is there anyway to settle this place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you cannot, at least not easily.  You *can* build stuff in it but you are limited as to what.  Some of the things that cannot be built are water purifiers, crops, guard posts, stores, scavenging stations, or artillery. As you said, you cannot build a settlement recruitment beacon either.

You *can* as noted in the comments, send settlers here from other settlements, but it would be difficult to keep them happy without being able to build the necessities.

Additional information about this location and its restrictions:

> If you side with the Brotherhood, you build the teleporter to teleport into the Institute in this location as part of the Molecular Level quest.  It is also used to construct parts for the Liberty Reprimed quest.

Source: Experience and [the Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Boston_Airport).

Comment: Actually, you don't have to do what the spoiler says, you can do it anywhere. The reason they have it is actually a different quest where you have to do something at Boston Airport.

Comment: I think you **can** send settlers to the Boston Airport from your other settlements, which at least gets settlers to that settlement without the use of a beacon. They won't be very happy, though... with this being a limited settlement in what you're allowed to build, you can't even build crops, water, etc.

Comment: It does appear you can send settlers to Boston Airport from other settlements. But as you stated, it wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: @king14nyr If you have excess food and water at other settlements, and a supply line, then they should be fed and watered at the Airport, unless that's also a special restriction that no supplies be brought in.

Answer (score 2):

You can build purifiers or pumps in the rubble or dirt at the NW corners, the purifier that produces10 water can be strategically placed in some of the rubble, i've done this with three so far. Then you have to send settlers there from other settlements and make sure you have caravan going to a settlement that produces enough food.

Answer (score 2):

To figure this out, you will need to break your ties with the Brotherhood of Steel by becoming an enemy to the faction by murdering a named BoS soldier. You will then need to eliminate the BoS by taking down the Prydwen through the Railroad quest Rockets' Red Glare, or by going through the Institute quest Airship Down. The Minutemen can take down the Prydwen in the post-game by going through the optional Minutemen quest With Our Powers Combined after becoming an enemy to the Brotherhood of Steel. You will then need to go into the Boston Airport Ruins and kill the Feral Ghouls that reside in there. After that, the Boston Airport has been cleared and the workshop becomes available again. You no longer have limited building options and it has become an ordinary settlement!

Note: With *Nuka-World* installed, it can be set up as a raider outpost after doing all of this.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Timmy Jim's answer, which addresses the vanilla issue, here are a few mods that will allow you to actually create a proper settlement at the Boston Airport.

- [Boston Airport Workbench Fix - Full Settlement Workbench](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/6084)
  This mod replaces the unique limited workbench with the standard one, so all building options are available. In addition, you can opt for a water pump that generates food (and gives a small bonus to Happiness).
- [Airport Workbench](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/4969)
  This mod does the same as the former, in that it replaces the limited-option workbench with a full-fledged one. The author here suggests making use of the following mod in addition to theirs:
- [Working Food Planters](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/1490)
  This mod "*let's you craft food planters*". It allows you to place interactive versions of the planters as seen in Graygarden. Which makes a lot of sense anyway.
- [Boston Airport - expanded and irrigated](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/12114)
  My preferred option, since it offers the most logical fixes: in addition—once again—to the fixed workbench it expands the buildable area into the water, allowing to use the beach to grow crops and the water to build purifiers.
- [Improved Boston Airport 2.0](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/12114)
  This does the same as the former mod, but with a few extras that you might or mightn't want: the build limit has been raised, the barricades are scrappable, the placing of map markers has been optimized, and it adds 5 BoS sentry bots that guard the airport perimeter.
- [All Settlements Extended!](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/25316)
  This mod also expands the buildable area, but does it for all settlements. So in case you prefer having all your settlement areas be enlarged, I suggest installing this mod and one of the fixed workbenches mods listed earlier.
- [Boston Airport Settlement Repaired](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/35101)
  I'm not sure how this mod behaves with the ones that expand the buildable area, so use this at your own risk, but it could be an interesting experiment. This mod restores the airport building to how it likely used to be, covering the entire settlement area by extending the current airport building, turning the region into what seems to be a waiting area. This gives you a roof and a larger second floor area (you can combine it with [Boston Airport Windows Transparency Fix](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/48429) to be able to actually look through the windows).
- [Bigger Boston airport settlement](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/37696)
  This mod expands the Boston Airport settlement area to include the large parking garage on the side opposite the water, increasing the size at least twofold.
- [Scrap Everything](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/5320)
  Lastly, a very general but helpful mod when it comes to building settlements. Does exactly what it says on the tin.

---

The reason behind this apparent shortcoming on Bethesda's behalf, is that

> the player needs to be able to build something here for the Brotherhood of Steel if taking their faction's side in the game.

I guess this is the reason they turned it into a pseudo-settlement.

This also means that, according to the author of the first mod from the list above

> **the cell is already really crowded with over 300 references to NPCs and stuff**. Starlight [Drive-In] has like 20.

Answer (score 1):

as of 2017 it is definitely possible to build water pumps on the rubble at the far end of the BA. Also you CAN build a radio tower. But nobody will come. Since it is BOS territory.

Answer (score 1):

You can successfully establish settlers here while siding with the BOS by going to other settlements and moving settlers to Boston Airport or use Rogue Settler Quests from the Mechanist to populate it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Im settling mine with robots. I built the Robot workbench there, i did put a generator and a bed there as it showed a need for them on the map but as far as settlers i just create robots, then make them run supplies between the castle and Vault 88.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).